# Get onClick element to return to the main element?

Tags: javascript

I'm awful with javascript and I'm having a problem with this one.

I'm using this code

```
<script> 
function changeNavigation(id){
   document.getElementById('members')
     .innerHTML=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
} 
</script>
```

and HTML

```
`<span onClick="changeNavigation('members')" >MEMBERS</span>
<span onClick="changeNavigation('help')" >HELP</span>`

<div id="members>...</div>

<div id="help" style="display: none;>...</div>
```

But I can't get `<span onClick="changeNavigation('members')" >MEMBERS</span>` to actually go to an element "members" without duplicating everything inside of it in another id.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure about the hard-coded id 'members' in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using only standard javascript, but personally I'd recommend going ahead and getting used to using jQuery. Here's an example jsfiddle using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/JnvCR/2/

---

Don't forget to include jQuery in your website:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much simpler and actually does what I need.

Comment: @MinaSimic Sure thing, I made a minor change to the code that specifies which `.active` elements to toggle off (just incase in the future you end up using it for other classes) http://jsfiddle.net/JnvCR/2/. Also if you wouldn't mind accepting the answer, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your syntax errors. Use onclick instead of onClick (pedantic). Make sure you close your attributes properly, you are missing a few closing " marks.

updated html

```
<span onclick="changeNavigation('members')" >MEMBERS</span>
<span onclick="changeNavigation('help')" >HELP</span>`

<div id="members">...</div>

<div id="help" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

There is also an error with your logic as you are simply replacing the contents of div#members with itself.

Updated JS without syntax errors, but still with dodgy logic

```
function changeNavigation(id){
 document.getElementById('members').innerHTML=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
}
```

Demo fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ADGCV/

As far as your actual question goes, can you explain what you would like to happen a bit better??

Here's a possible solution http://jsfiddle.net/ADGCV/1/